# SQL Server on update move to separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

My company requires a column in the `Customer` table which will show the number of previous addresses for any customer. This number must update automatically whenever the address is updated.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER deleted_address ON tblcustomer
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 end
```

So far I have this but I've come to an issue where I don't know how make it so if an address of a customer is edited it adds the old address to a new column called `PreviousAddress` and then updates the `CustomerAddress`

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleted_address ON tblcustomer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE (CustomerAddress)
    UPDATE t
    SET t.[PreviousAddress] = t.PreviousAddress + 1,
        t.CustomerAddress = i.CustomerAddress
    FROM tblcustomer t
    JOIN INSERTED i ON t.customer_id = i.customer_id
END
GO
```

Comment: So, unless the `CustomerAddress` column is affected, my updates will simply be ignored?

Comment: Good point, I updated it to after update...I must have missed that one earlier. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

To update previous address, you can write a trigger like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateAddress
   ON  Customer
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT ID FROM DELETED)
    UPDATE dbo.Customer SET PreviousAddress = (SELECT Address FROM DELETED )
    WHERE ID = @id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AFTER UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleted_address ON tblcustomer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON


   IF UPDATE (Address)
      UPDATE t SET countPrev = countPrev + 1, oldAddress = d.Address
      FROM tblcustomer t
      JOIN INSERTED i ON t.customer_id = i.customer_id
      JOIN DELETED d  ON t.customer_id = d.customer_id

END
```